# 0 RPM Fan speed (monitoring) but the fans are spinning

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling

I would like to troubleshoot an issue that I came across. I recently checked "Armoury Crate" and saw that I have 0 fan rpms although the fans are spinning.

Seems like a lot of people have the same issue but I could not find a solution so far.

I have a CPU water cooling system and I already did set the CPU fan speed in BIOS on "ignore" to avoid "FAN Error" message after booting up the computer.

But I still couldn't figure out why I can't see the RPM of my fans. I'd highly appreciate help.

[image: Monitoring 0 RPM]

Comment: I just checked my own fans using GPU-Z, and all are at zero. Perhaps both our computers do not require the fans to maintain room temperature. I too have water cooling.

Comment: Thanks for your message @harrymc - I already thought that something is wrong on my hardware or a Pin doesn't work. It would be lovely to actually see RPM's of the fans or to be able to control them. No matter what I do they always spin the same.

Comment: What is your computer model and GPU? Try perhaps [SpeedFan](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) - it can monitor and control.

Comment: No Model since I built it. I currently have a RTX3090 Suprim X

Comment: Give then the models of the motherboard and CPU.

Comment: SpeedFan seems to not detect my fans. When I click on configure -> speeds there is no Fan.
CPU - i9-9900K
GPU - RTX3090 Suprim X
MB - Rog Strix Z390-E

Comment: SpeedFan is an older product and may not work with too modern hardware. There are others such as Core Temp and hwinfo.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was checking CoreTemp and HWInfo and both didn't work either. Now I installed L-Connect3 from Lian LI and it is perfectly working.

Comment: I summarized our comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the lack of support for too-modern hardware
in multiple free products, such as SpeedFan, CoreTemp and HWInfo.

The poster found that L-Connect3 from Lian LI works well.